# Sbt script and different resources and source directories

Tags: java, scala, build, sbt

I am making a build.sbt script for a java project. As this project does not follow the standard structure (as src/main/java) I need to point sbt script to the correct one (as I have made for gradle script in which i have changed both source and resources directories).
The structure of my project is:

```
src
  packageName
    Main.java
  resources
test
```

I have search a lot but I don't find anything, the documentation for build java project with sbt does not make any example.
Finally, I cannot change the structure of my project.

That is my actual sbt script:

```
organization := "something"

name := "name"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
```

It returns

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: No main class detected.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have actually found the solution:

```
unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile += baseDirectory.value / "src"

resourceDirectory in Compile := baseDirectory.value / "src"
```

Adding these two lines makes the flow of compilation work.
(more details on: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Howto-Customizing-Paths.html)